# Нужно, чтобы парсер переходил по ссылкам и собирал все информацию

Tags: python

Мне нужно, чтобы парсер собирал все ссылки с одной страницы, после чего переходил по этим ссылкам и собирал оттуда всю информацию. Но при выполнении кода выводится только последний компонент списка `svarka`.

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

URL = 'https://ptk-svarka.ru/catalog/apparaty-poluavtomaticheskoy-svarki-mig'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}
FILE = 'svarka.csv'



def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_Stranic(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='b-grid__item js-product-item')
    stranica_svarka=[]
    for item in items:
        stranica_svarka.append(
            item.find('a', class_='b-products__text').get('href'),
            )
    return stranica_svarka

def get_html_vivod(stranic):
    for url in stranic:
        r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
        r = r.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('article', class_='b-product__wrapper')
        svarka = []
        for item in items:
            svarka.append({
                'title': item.find('h1', class_='b-product__title').get_text(strip=True)
                })
    return svarka

def parse():
    URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip()
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        stranic = get_Stranic(html.text)
        svarka = get_html_vivod(stranic)
        print (svarka)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в разных областях видимости. В вашем случае `svarka` живет только в цикле `for url in stranic` и каждую итерацию обновляется новым значением `[]`, удаляя предыдущий прогресс.

Нужно вынести инициализацию листа `svarka` на тот же уровень отступов, что и `return`.

```
def get_html_vivod(stranic):
    svarka = []
    for url in stranic:
        # ...
    return svarka
```